# NoSuchMethodError with Retrofit2, Gson & OkHttpClient

Tags: java, maven, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to get the a list containing data from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/). I've managed to do so using another method. However, I'm facing an issue when using Retrofit to generate the methods.

```
static final String API_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX";
static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat(API_DATE_FORMAT)
    .create();

OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .client(httpClient.build())
    .build();
```

I then later call

```
Controller controller = retrofit.create(Controller.class);

Call<List<Album>> call = controller.getAlbums();
Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Running: " + call.toString());
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Album>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Album>> call, Response<List<Album>> response) {
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("VROOM");
        assert response.body() != null;
        response.body().forEach(album -> Bukkit.broadcastMessage(album.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Album>> call, Throwable t) {
        getServer().getLogger().info(t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Controller class

```
public interface Controller {
    
    @GET("/albums")
    Call<List<Album>> getAlbums();

}
```

Album class

```
public class Album {
    private int userId;
    private int id;
    private String title;
}
```

Full Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher"
[22:47:00 WARN]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader;
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[22:47:00 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

pom.xml. I've tried multiple versions such as going back to older ones and trying. Still getting the same error. All of the libraries underneath gets produced with the jar. I still get the NoSuchMethodError.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>yeet</groupId>
    <artifactId>yeeted</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Yeeted</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[Maven dependency tree log](https://pastebin.com/JMn1JrwU) (pastebin)

Comment: Try doing `mvn dependency:tree` and check for dependency conflicts

Comment: I got `BUILD SUCCESS` after doing `mvn dependency:tree`. It's really strange, every library gets compiled with the jar, yet I get the NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Can you update the output of dependency:tree in the question?

Comment: Added [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/JMn1JrwU)

Comment: I created a fresh new project and ran the sample class [SimpleService from retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleService.java). It worked completely fine, however, in my current project it did not. My pom.xml now shows everything.

Comment: Try removing gson dependency from pom. converter-gson will automatically add the compatible gson dependency,

Comment: Getting the same error. Maybe it has something to do with runtime? Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I'm trying to access the API from https://docs.tebex.io/plugin/ - https://github.com/tebexio/BuycraftX using Retrofit. I built their jar and added it to my project and Retrofit works fine now. It's definitely something in my pom.xml which is not working.